# Objective-C: "overriding" properties -- Alternatives?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, design-patterns, properties

I've found it extraordinarily useful to "override" properties. Here are two such cases:

1) A `UIView` subclass with `CAShapeLayer` as a backing store:

```
@interface MYView : UIView
    // Redeclare "layer" property of UIView:
    @property (nonatomic, readonly, retain) CAShapeLayer *layer;
@end

@implementation
    // Use CAShapeLayer as backing store
    + (Class)layerClass { return [CAShapeLayer class]; }
@end
```

2) A `UITableViewController` subclass with a `UITableView` subclass:

```
@interface MYTableViewController
    // Redeclare "tableView" property of UITableViewController:
    @property (nonatomic, retain) MYTableView *tableView;
@end
```

I get flawless results in the above situations, but I'd rather not do it for two reasons: it's considered **bad form** and it's **unpredictable** (it will break classes in many situations). So what are my alternatives?

In case (1) above, the alternative is repeated type refinement--casting `self.layer` to `CAShapeLayer*` everywhere I reference it. I find it hard to believe that this is considered the "cleaner" option. Am I missing something?

Comment: In the second example, you can make a `UIViewController` instead that contains a `UITableView` (or your custom class)...

Comment: Whoever gave you the impression that subclasses weren't supposed to be more specific is completely wrong.  What you are doing is considered good practice, inline with fundamental OO as it's been practiced since the 80's.  The other way around is the dangerous way: casting down the inheritance tree creates the opportunity for bad message sends and undefined behavior.  In most languages, casting down is considered a type error without explicitly showing the compiler/runtime it can be done safely.

Comment: Thanks, CodaFi, that is my understanding as far as OO goes. But, unless I'm mistaken, this StackOverflow answer brings up an interesting catch when it comes to Objective-C properties: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7085926/overriding-property-declarations-in-objective-c). See the "Properties" section of Kevin Ballard's answer.

Comment: well, Kevins answer is correct, but i.e. the layer property is intended to be overwritten. that's why you also have to overwrite `layerClass:`. Overwriting `view` or `tableView` in VC subclasses is also usually save, as the user (99% if time: you) is aware of a certain type it must have. You could also write custom getter and setter to perform a runtime type check, so it will be impossible to use the VC with a view that isn't of your desired type. BTW: I'm nit aware of any reason to subclass UITableView. Are you?

Comment: Those are fair points viking. It's just somewhat frustrating that this pattern isn't better documented by Apple. I have in fact encountered situations where refining a property's type by "overriding" it in a subclass has lead to broken behavior. And you're right about overriding accessor methods. At risk of going off topic, yes, I have encountered a situation where subclassing UITableView was necessary for tighter control over scrolling behavior (UIScrollViewDelegate simply wasn't cutting it).

Comment: Also, the specific issue Kevin was discussing is not about overriding properties per se, it is about changing their type signatures. In the case of `+layerClass` that is not a problem, its return type is not an instance of the class with a new type, it is always the class object itself (of type `Class`).