# Type of property does not match type of accessor

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios8, xcode6

Using Xcode 6 Beta 4, targeting iOS 8:

I'm using Core Data and [Mogenerator](http://rentzsch.github.io/mogenerator/) together. If you're not familiar with "Mogen", skip to the bottom. When Mogen generates a NSManagedObject subclass for an entity, it does this:

```
@interface MyEntityID : NSManagedObjectID {}
@end

@interface _MyEntity : NSManagedObject {}

- (MyEntityID*)objectID;

----------------------------------------------------------------------------

@implementation _MyEntity

- (KJMWorkoutID*)objectID {
    return (KJMWorkoutID*)[super objectID];
}
```

It's kind of handy I guess. NSManagedObject has an objectID property, all _MyEntity is doing is overriding it's getter to return a MyEntityID so that we can tell it's an ID specifically for our _MyEntityClass.

So, back to my question. I want to compare two MyEntityIDs by checking that they are not equal:

```
if (![self.objectID isEqual:self.previousID])
```

I get this warning:

`Type of property 'objectID' does not match type of accessor 'objectID'`

Okay, I understand that the property is NSManagedObjectID, but we're calling the accessor method Mogen has written which returns MyEnytityID. Even the code completion recognises this.

How is it still seeing the NSManagedObjectID property type for objectID of NSManagedObject?
Should I silence the warning somehow?
Is it likely just a Xcode 6 Beta thing? (it doesn't happen in Xcode 5)

What's Mogen:

Mogen is just a helpful tool that generates subclasses of NSManagedObject for your data model entities. It's kind of like what Xcode does, but doesn't erase any custom code you write every time you re-generate the subclasses and it gives you a whole bunch of nice methods to use for creating new entities etc. If the under bar prefixed class name thing there is something new to you too, it's just the way that Mogen stops itself from overwriting any custom code you write.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The problem is unrelated to the Xcode 6 beta release, but due to the fact that the declaration of `objectID` changed in iOS 8. Up to iOS 7, it was declared as an
*instance method*:

```
- (NSManagedObjectID *)objectID;
```

As of iOS 8/OS X 10.10, it is declared as a read-only *property*:

```
@property (nonatomic, readonly, strong) NSManagedObjectID *objectID;
```

As explained in https://stackoverflow.com/a/7086119/1187415, you can override an 
instance method in a subclass with a method having a more specialized return value,
in this case

```
- (MyEntityID *)objectID;
```

But is seems to be problematic to override a *property* with a more specialized return value
(and doing so would cause the identical warning with Xcode 5).

The following seems to work with both the "old" and the "new" SDKs:
In "_MyEntity.h", replace

```
- (MyEntityID*)objectID;
```

by

```
@property (nonatomic, readonly, strong) MyEntityID *objectID;
```

and in "_MyEntity.m", remove the `- (MyEntityID*)objectID` method and add

```
@dynamic objectID;
```

However, these files are always re-created by Mogenerator, so this is not a 
satisfying solution.
I would recommend to file a bug report to the Mogenerator people to find a solution
that is compatible with the iOS 8/OS X 10.10 SDKs.

I could not find a compiler option to suppress this warning (it is not marked with
"-W..." so that a "-Wno..." option would suppress it.

As a **workaround**, you can replace `self.objectID` by `[self objectID]`, which does 
not cause the warning.

Comment: Fantastic answer, thank you! That other answer you've linked to is very good too.

Comment: Is there a Clang override for this warning? We (currently) have a lot of these

Comment: @itsthejb: Good question. It seems that there is no "-Wno..." compiler option to suppress the warning.

Comment: Indeed. Usually Clang warnings emit the appropriate warning flag. How annoying! We have far too many of these to use Clang diagnostic

Comment: @itsthejb if you're using Mogen like me and facing this issue, someone fixed it: https://github.com/rentzsch/mogenerator/pull/201. Just clone the repo and build, happy days!

Comment: Fantastic answer. Mogenerator needs lots of updating, really.

Comment: In Xcode 7 beta this issue is treated as error, not warning. Replacing instance method with property works great!

Answer (score 3):

@Martin R's answer is correct, but for those arriving here from now on, Mogenerator has been updated to [v1.28](https://github.com/rentzsch/mogenerator/releases/download/1.28/mogenerator-1.28.dmg) and fixes this issue.

Comment: Thanks for making it more clear that Mogen has been updated :). I mentioned it in my comment on @Marin R's answer but you have to click show comments to see it.